# How to unit test a controller method with spring boot and mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I've read a couple articles and seen a few videos and I though I had a grasp on how Mockito works, but still I'm unable to implement any test to my controller.

First of all, I have the following service class, which performs a request to an external API:

```
@Service
public class MovieService {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    
    public MovieResponse getMovieResponse() {
        ResponseEntity<MovieResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.
                getForEntity("{base_url}", MovieResponse.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }

}
```

Then my controller calls this method and performs the sorting operation on the data:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {
    
    @Autowired
    MovieService movieService = new MovieService();

    @GetMapping(value="/movies")
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {
        List<Movie> movies = movieService.getMovieResponse().getMovies();
        movies.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getMovieName));
        return movies ;
    
    }
}
```

And so I tried to Mock the service response in order to test my method and verify that a sorting is happening.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MovieControllerTest{
    
    private MovieService movieService;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Before
    void setup() {
        movieService = Mockito.mock(MovieService.class);
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void getAllMoviesTest() throws Exception {
        Movie movie1 = new Movie("Marley & Me", "2008");
        Movie movie2 = new Movie("Avatar", "2012");

        List<Movie> allMovies = Arrays.asList(movie2, movie1);
        List<Movie> expectedMovies = Arrays.asList(movie1, movie2);
        
        MovieResponse firstMovieResponse = new MovieResponse();
        firstMovieResponse.setMovies(allMovies);
        
        MovieResponse expectedMovieResponse = new MovieResponse();
        firstMovieResponse.setMovies(expectedMovies);
        
        Mockito.when(movieService.getMovieResponse())
                .thenReturn(firstMovieResponse);
        
        mockMvc.perform(get("/movies"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect((ResultMatcher) expectedMovieResponse);
  }
}
```

I've tried several approaches, but I think this is the closest I've got, but I get a `NullPointerException` in the line:

```
Mockito.when(movieService.getMovieResponse())
                    .thenReturn(firstMovieResponse);
```

And the stack trace prints the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.movieservice.controller.MovieControllerTest.getAllMoviesTest(MovieControllerTest.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace. What line do you get the NPE on?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it points out this line as the NPE causer:  `Mockito.when(movieService.getMovieResponse())
                .thenReturn(firstMovieResponse);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually unit test implies direct invocation of subject class and stubbing its dependencies. Code sample provided relies on `@Autowired` annotation which requires Spring context to be present in order to work.

Test case tries to invoke `mockMvc` which is not available, hence `NullPointerException` is thrown.

You have to explicitly annotate test class with `@SpringBootTest` so that context is created. Additionally, `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` has to be included so that `MockMvc` is available for autowiring.

Last, but not least, since we use Spring's context so much, instead of using plain Mockito, we have to wrap it with Spring's `@MockBean` instead, which will inject stub into controller.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MovieControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void getAllMoviesTest() throws Exception {
        // TODO: when(movieService...).thenReturn(...);
        // TODO: mockMvc.perform(...);
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [Spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing) for additional information.

Comment: I guess what really was missing was that AutoConfigure line at the beggining of the test

Answer (score 3):

This might come in handy if your goal is to control the ranking.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MovieControllerTest{
    
    @InjectMocks
    private MovieController movieController;

    @Mock
    private MovieService movieService;
    
    @Test
    void getAllMoviesTest() throws Exception {
        //Given
        Movie movie1 = new Movie("Marley & Me", "2008");
        Movie movie2 = new Movie("Avatar", "2012");
        final List<Movie> allMovies = Arrays.asList(movie2, movie1);
        
        MovieResponse firstMovieResponse = new MovieResponse();
        firstMovieResponse.setMovies(allMovies);
        
        Mockito.when(movieService.getMovieResponse()).thenReturn(firstMovieResponse);
        
        //When
        List<Movie> actualMovieList = movieController.getAllMovies();

        //Then
        assertThat(actualMovieList).containsExactly(movie1, movie2);
  }
}
```

**@InjectMocks**, to inject mock class into the test class.

PS. You can also use something different to test the ordering.

```
assertThat(actualMovieList).containsExactly(movie1, movie2);
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but using your example I get the actual response from the API wich is an enormous list of movies, and so the assertion fails

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the setup in getAllMoviesTest inside the setup function annotated by @Before. You also need to annotate movieService with @MockBean in the test class but as someone said before, look at the stack trace to find out where the NullPointerException is occurring.

Comment: I've checked and added the stack trace to the question, still I'm unable to understand why is it raising a NPE

Answer (score 1):

I think the NPE is coming as the movieservice didn’t get mocked and the movieService object could be null, so it might be giving NPE. Try to put @MockBean above the moveservice.
Try to run the test in debug mode.